# How do I find out if my email server sends out an ip address with my emails?

Tags: email, smtp

I read in a publication that most major email providers include your ip address when sending out emails.  The exception being gmail.  I'm told this can give you alot of spam. Here at work, we use our webhost for sending out emails, and I wanted to find out if the email server we are sending mail from includes the ip address with the email.

Is it a simple matter of connecting with telnet?  Our email uses some sort of encryption as well, so I'm not so sure I would be able to login to it with telnet, and I've never heard of anyone logging into an email server using ssh (for purposes of using the smtp protocol, not bash).

Comment: **"I read in a publication that most major email providers include your ip address when sending out emails."** - if by "your IP address" they mean your email server's IP address, that's called "working correctly" and yes they do that. If they meant your computer's IP address then they're wrong for most 'normal' providers but I think some webmail providers do this. Not that it matters. **"I'm told this can give you alot of spam"** - Either there's a lot of back story missing or the person that told you that is the world's only living brain doner.

Comment: How would including 'your IP address' result in you getting a lot of SPAM?  The messages you send will include your email address, which will has your domain name, which will resolve to the IP address of your mail server, which is almost certainly the host that will accept the SPAM messages.

Answer (score 3):

According to RFC 2822:

> The only required header fields are the origination date field and the
>   originator address field(s).

So yes, if your web server is the originator of the email then it's ip address will be in the header and is required to be in the header.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I correctly understand your 'include your ip address when sending out emails' but if you mean that IP address is being included to your mail message you could send email to yourself (on same or another email account belonging to you) and see message source (most clients give you this ability). There you should see all mail headers (including service ones like determining path of SMTP servers that mail traveled to get in to your inbox) - check if there is originating IP of sender in your case.